Strange behavior of std::pair containing references
I was curious about std::pair's handling of references since c++20 as re-seating references that are inside structs are now legal via custom member functions. See this question. I have code that uses pairs with pointers to vector<vector<Stuff>> I use to sort through various data aspects. I like to get rid of pointers where possible and use references. It failed misserably with no warnings or compiler errors so I wrote this simple code:
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using std::pair, std::vector, std::string, std::cout;

int main()
{
    string s1{ " MyFirst" };
    string s2{ " MySecond" };
    vector < pair<string, string&>> v; v.reserve(2);    // prevent reallocation
    v.push_back({ "string_b", s2 });
    v.push_back({ "string_a", s1 });
    cout << v[0].first << v[0].second << '\n';
    cout << v[1].first << v[1].second << '\n';

    // sort so string_a comes first
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](pair<string, string&> a, pair<string, string&> b) {
        return a.second < b.second; });

    cout << '\n';
    cout << v[0].first << v[0].second << '\n';
    cout << v[1].first << v[1].second << '\n';

    // outputs
/*
    string_b MySecond
    string_a MyFirst

    string_a MySecond
    string_b MySecond
*/


No compiler errors but very strange results that make no sense based on either prior to c++20 as it is re-seating one of the pairs, or after when it could produce expected results.
This was coded on MSVC. Appears GCC produces the same results: compiler explorer
Is there any explanation as to what std::pair is doing?
Some discussion about whether you can re-seat references. One didn't used to be able to but c++20 allows it in classes though it requires writing a custom member. Here's an example of a simple MyPair class with a string and a string ref that workse as expected is and legal code.
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::pair, std::vector, std::string, std::cout;

struct MyPair {
    string first;
    string& second;
    MyPair(const string& s1, string &s2) : first(s1), second(s2) {}
    MyPair& operator=(const MyPair& arg) {
        if (this == &arg)
            return *this;
        std::destroy_at(this);
        return *std::construct_at(this, arg);
    }
};


int main()
{
    string s1{ " MyFirst" };
    string s2{ " MySecond" };
    vector<MyPair> v;
    v.push_back({ "string_b", s2 });
    v.push_back({ "string_a", s1 });
    cout << v[0].first << v[0].second << '\n';
    cout << v[1].first << v[1].second << '\n';

    // sort so string_a comes first
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](MyPair &a, MyPair &b) {
        return a.second < b.second; });

    cout << '\n';
    cout << v[0].first << v[0].second << '\n';
    cout << v[1].first << v[1].second << '\n';
}
    // outputs
/*
    string_b MySecond
    string_a MyFirst

    string_a MyFirst
    string_b MySecond
*/



Regarding reseating references: I think you misunderstood something. See https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#reseating-refs

Sorting will copy or move data around. And references can't be copied or moved. Think of a reference as an alias of something else, every time you use the reference, you are actually using the the object it references.

@TedLyngmo That was true pre c++ 20. references  can now be re-seated. See this which applies to references as well a consts.

@Someprogrammerdude. As of c++20 they could be but apparently hasn't been done for pair.

@doug Ok, that creates a new object in place of the old one, so I wouldn't call it reseating really, but I get the point. That's not new in C++20 though. It works fine earlier too. C++11 example

@TedLyngmo. Prior to c++20 the basic life rules said you couldn't alter consts or references once initialized upon creation. That changed radically in c++20. The term is "transparently replaced" I was hoping to see it used in pair. If it worked in c++11 it was UB.

@doug Ok, that's fascinating. I don't see it as altering the reference since we end the lifetime by calling the destructor and construct a new object in the old object's place - but I will have to read up on it for sure.

@doug -- as far as I remember you were always allowed to create a new object in the place of previously destroyed. There was never reference reseating neither before nor after c++20.

@Gene  You could release the storage and reuse it but you couldn't directly refer to it's members. You had to go through std::launder which mad it pretty much unusable. c++ 20 eliminated the need to use std::launder for that purpose.

@doug -- that's simply an artifact of construct_at that was introduced in C++20, which is return ::new (voidify(*location)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...); -- it doesn't require location to be a pointer to a living object, there is no need for launder.

@Genestd::launder was required prior to c++20 because even if you released the memory for an object and constructed a new one in it's place, you couldn't reference consts or references and get the new values. At least technically. But you could through launder. Since c++20 this is no longer needed.

std::pair's move/copy-assignment and swap do not reseat reference elements. Instead they are defined to act on the referenced objects, such as if you wrote e.g. lhs.first = rhs.first or swap(lhs.first, rhs.first) to operate on the elements, except that the value category of lhs and rhs is according to the reference qualifications on the overloads.
So, when std::sort attempts to swap the two members, it will not change what objects the references refer to, but instead swap the string values contained in s1 and s2.
As a consequence you violate the std::sort semantic requirements, causing undefined behavior. The comparator does not consistently compare the objects in the range after swaps.

The interface of std::pair is older than C++20 and even in C++20 the approach for "reseating references" via transparent replacement is not useable in all cases. In particular it wouldn't work e.g. if the pair is a mutable subobject of a const complete object.
Your suggested implementation of MyPair::operator= suffers from even more edge cases than necessary. For example it has UB if MyPair is used as a base class, or a member with [[no_unique_address]] attribute.
And in any case, while this technical possibility of replacing references exists, I do not think that anyone has the intention to make this actual semantics used in (or even supported by) the library. A reference is intended to be non-reseatable. If reseatable semantics are intended, std::reference_wrapper should be used. That's already well-established in the library.

Yep, transparent replacement doesn't work (is UB) for any top level const objects mutable elements or not. Looks like std::swap would have the same problem. Defined behavior for pair but certainly violates the expectation of what swap would do. Actually, not even defined behavior since the order isn't specified.

@doug It is pretty consistent with the rest of the standard library and consistent with the intended meaning of a reference: Any action that is normally applied to an object is applied to the object referenced by the reference instead. And if that is not intended, then std::reference_wrapper should be used. A reference behaves exactly as if its referenced object was put in its place instead.

I actually tried reference_wrapper in my code base. Couldn't get it to work. Not sure why as I've used it before but didn't spend a lot of time on it. Think I'll stick with the pointer approach. Simple and clear.

@doug "Actually, not even defined behavior since the order isn't specified: On pair itself the operations are well-defined. The problem is just your comparator for std::sort which isn't consistently comparing the elements of the range after swap operations. Had you compared on the first element instead, then it would be well-defined.

Well, std::sort never had to consider such things in the past. I tend to think of const and reference members as invariants to a specific object. I think of an object assignment as replacing the whole object with a new one subject to the same invariants as the type requires.

I actually tried reference_wrapper in my code base. Couldn't get it to work. Looks like you do something wrong. All you need to do in your example is replace string& in pair's argument with std::reference_wrapper<string> and add .get() or static_cast<std::string>() when accessing wrapped object for printing, you even don't need to modify callback's lambda, since conversion will be done implicitly.

Works fine in my example. It just didn't work in my code base with vector<vector<Stuff>> No idea why. Too hard to simplify to post here.

@sklott  Thanks. Didn't realize I needed second.get() for access. Odd. Now works with my code base!  OTOH, it seems overly complex to use the reference_wrapper so I'll stick with pointers. They seem clearer.


Is there any explanation as to what std::pair is doing?

Regarding question above, the result of the following code snippet added at the end of your example will most likely surprise you:
cout << "s1" << s1 << '\n'; // prints "s1 MySecond"
cout << "s2" << s2 << '\n'; // prints "s2 MySecond"

There was no any references re-setting or any other advanced operations.
The simple fact is that references are not pointers. So data copy/swap, somewhere deep inside the sorting code generated, instead of swapping the second pair's parameter as you expected, generated code overwriting referenced strings.

Thanks. That is indeed what is happening. So swapping two pairs can overwrite the referred values. And that explains the crazy stuff I saw when I changed from pointers to reference in my code base. I'm  not sure what the use of that behavior would be but it clearly is the way pair works.
